# Can't select dynamically generated HTML-elements (generated with Handlebars Block helpers)

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I am working on a Flask-based chat app and am generating the below HTML using a Handlebars JavaScript-template. In my JavaScript code I would like to select the `<a>`-Tag (`'#delete-message'`) element and add an `onclick` functionality to it. The `<div>`s that contain the elements are chat messages, so they are generated dynamically. Now when someone clicks "Delete", I want them to delete the message. But no matter what I try, none of the below options even select (return an array/collection of) my "Delete"s:

I tried:

```
const dels = document.getElementById('chat_log').getElementsByTagName('a');

const dels = document.getElementsByClassName('delete_message');
```

The following two don't work because I understand querySelectorAll returns a static list and my content is dynamic, but I tried:

```
const dels = document.querySelectorAll('.delete_message');

const dels = document.querySelectorAll('#delete_message');
```

HTML snippet is:

```
    <script id="chat_log" type="text/template">
      {% raw -%}
        {{#each values}}
        <div class=container>
            <b> {{this.sender}}: </b>
            <p>{{this.text}}</p>
            <p hidden>{{this.id}}</p>
            <span class="time-left">{{this.time}}</span>
            <span class="right-side"><a class="delete_message" id="delete_message" href="">Delete</a></span>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
      {%- endraw %}
    </script>
```

I then want to add the functionality using `.forEach`, but the array/collection/nodes returned always have a length of 0 (i.e. no elements), no matter how many chat messages there are. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Problem one is you will have multiple elements with `id="delete_message"` . Id **must** be unique. Showing an example of rendered HTML would also be helpful, even better would be a [mcve]. Further more, if your elements are added *after* the page has loaded then any event listeners will not be added. One thing to help here is "event delegation"

Answer (score 0):

[Event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) to the rescue.

With elements that are added after page load you either need to add the event listener when the object is created, or better still use event delegation. With event delegation to add a listener to a common parent element and add an event listener to that. You then can use event properties to perform the appropriate task.

For the example below I've replaced your handlebar template with a template literal, just because it's easier for a quick example. I've also added a common element which will contain the chat.

```js
const chat = document.getElementById("chat");
//Event delegation
chat.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //Do stuff when delete button clicked
  if (event.target.classList.contains("delete_message")) {
    alert("about to to delete item id: " + event.target.href);
  }
});

const data = [{
    sender: "Bill",
    text: "'sup?",
    id: 1,
    time: "12:11"
  },
  {
    sender: "Ben",
    text: "Hey! How you doin'?",
    id: 2,
    time: "12:12"
  },
  {
    sender: "Bill",
    text: "'Great! And you?",
    id: 1,
    time: "12:13"
  }
];


//DONT ADD CONTENT THIS WAY IT's FOR DEMO ONLY
data.forEach(function(send) {
  let template = `
    <div class=container>
        <b> ${send.sender}: </b>
        <p>${send.text}</p>
        <p hidden>${send.id}</p>
        <span class="time-left">${send.time}</span>
        <span class="right-side"><a class="delete_message" id="delete_message_${send.id}" href="#${send.id}">Delete</a></span>
    </div>`;
  chat.innerHTML += template;
});
```

```html
<div id="chat"></div>
```